# Truffle migration contract not found - but it's there!

Tags: truffle

I have a feeling this is going to be a forehead-slapper, but here goes...

I'm attempting to run Truffle's "Pet Shop" demo app on AWS.  The **truffle compile** command ran fine, with a few non-fatal warnings but nothing major. It completed with...

```
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts
```

...as expected. But **truffle migrate** is failing, and it seems to be not seeing the contents of the file successfully created at **contracts/Migrations.json**.

```
$ truffle migrate
Using network 'development'.
Error: Could not find built Migrations contract: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
```

However, the file is there, and seems fine.  Any idea why this is failing?

Also worth noting: I've got two console windows running (both SSH'd into the same AWS EC2 instance), and the second of the two is running **testrpc**.  It is "listening" and does tell me...

```
Listening on localhost:8545
net_version
eth_accounts
```

...when I attempt the migration, but nothing beyond that.

Thanks for any nudge in the right direction!

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, but had switched to using Ganache. I was able to fix my migration issue by deleting `./build` and re-compiling/migrating.

Comment: Thanks Justin - yup!  Deleting the build subdirectory and re-running **truffle compile** and **truffle migrate** solved the problem.  (I coulda sworn I'd done the same yesterday, but I guess not.)  :)

Answer (score 4):

you can delete your build directory and try again

```
rm -rf build
truffle compile
truffle migrate
```

oneliner

```
rm -rf build && truffle compile && truffle migrate
```

Comment: This is STILL a problem today. Why does it do this? Does truffle know about this? It's very timewasting for developers.

Comment: try becoming a core contributor and fix it 

Answer (score 1):

`truffle migrate --reset` cleans up your build directory and builds your contracts again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue as Jesse and I followed Harry's instructions on deleting the build directory and I recompiled and it was fine.